# Copy the a href value to a textbox onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I'm trying to copy the value (the displayed name) of the link onClick to the textbox. Is it possible ?

The following is my sloppy attempt to make it work -

```
<div class="service_list">
    <ul style="list-style-type:square; display:none;" id="ullist">
        <li><a href="#" class="service1">Service 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="service2">Service 2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="button">    <a href="#" download="servicename.txt" class="button" id="button">Download</a>

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="list">  <a href="#" class="list" id="list">List of Services</a>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the JS -

```
var link_selected = document.querySelector('.service_list'); //edited
var input_field = document.getElementById("input");
link_selected.onclick = function (e) {
    var selected = document.querySelector('.service_list').value; //edited
    input_field.value = selected;
};
```

here is the JSFiddle for the same :
https://jsfiddle.net/aishwarya26/rebpb5h2/

Comment: Correct your code ,

service_list is a class not id and you are using #service_list instead of .service_list

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: check this 

https://jsfiddle.net/rebpb5h2/2/

Comment: Why do you have jQuery tagged on this question, you seem to be using the DOM?

Comment: That's because I'm open to a JQuery solution as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a click handler to each link in the `#ullist` element then set teh value of the text box

```
var text = document.getElementById('textbox');
var anchor = document.querySelector('#button');

var links = document.querySelectorAll('#ullist a');
for(var  i = 0;i< links.length;i++){
    links[i].onclick = function(){
        text.value = this.textContent || this.innerText
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L2ogujk0/)

---

Using jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $text = $('#textbox');
    $('#ullist a').click(function () {
        $text.val($(this).text());
    });

    $('#button').click(function (e) {
        var textbox_text = $text.val();
        var textbox_file = new Blob([textbox_text], {
            "type": "application/bat"
        });

        this.href = URL.createObjectURL(textbox_file);
        this.download = "servicename.txt";
    });

    $('#list').click(function (e) {
        $('#ullist').toggle();
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L2ogujk0/2/)

Answer (score 2):

As JQuery is tagged, this could be simply done with JQuery!

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //e = $(this).attr('href');//this gets the href
    e = $(this).text();//This gets the text
    $('input').val(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly>
<a href="http://google.com">Google<a>
<a href="http://booble.com">Booble<a>
<a href="http://doodle.com">Doodle<a>
<a href="http://coocle.com">Coocle<a>
<a href="http://roorle.com">Roorle<a>
```

Comment: Actually this copies the URL and I only wanted the value displayed by the link.

Comment: @AishwaryaL then you need to modify your question - this answer is the correct answer for the question you asked.

Comment: I did write (displayed name) in the question. Maybe the question I framed is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Added the code to get the values inside `<a>` tags and left the code to get href as a comment!

Comment: And I think @gnack referred to the question itself: *Copy the a href value to a textbox onclick *

Answer (score 1):

Use a click trigger on page load like this, If you are willing to dabble in a bit of jquery:

```js
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#textbox').val($(this).html());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service_list">
    <ul style="list-style-type:square; display:none;" id="ullist">
        <li><a href="#" class="service1">Service 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="service2">Service 2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="button">    <a href="#" download="servicename.txt" class="button" id="button">Download</a>

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="list">  <a href="#" class="list" id="list">List of Services</a>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: var select = document.querySelector('a#list');
 i think this should be 
var select = document.querySelector('#list');

Answer (score 1):

you can also use live jquery click for this

```
$(document).on('click','.service1,.service2',function(){
    $("#textbox").val($(this).html());
});
```